# E4 lifeCycleURI property for fragment plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am new to Eclipse 4. I am trying to refactor existing application and move some domain related UI and code to fragment plugin. In existing application I have used lifeCycleURI property of plugin to link java class to register some services at IEclipseContext. But fragment tag at plugin.xml do not recognizes 'property name="lifeCycleURI"'.

How can I register life cycle manager code for fragment plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.products` extension supports the life cycle class, you can't define life cycles for plugins or fragments.

If you want to define OSGi services you can do that with a `Component Definition`. OSGi services are automatically added to the `IEclipseContext`.

You can also use a `ContextFunction` to lazily add to the context. see [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4ContextFunctions/article.html)

You can also add to the context using an `Addon`

Comment: Thanks @greg-449, that is very useful. Could you explain the `Addon` option a little more in detail?

Comment: Add Addon is something you specify in the Add-ons list in the application.e4xmi (or a fragment) and lets you run arbitrary code during startup